# I got Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted when upload a file

Tags: php, file, caching, memory, wamp

I'm currently developping a PHP website and I need to store files in my database.
I'm using a LONGBLOB to store files such as PDF,PPTX,...
The file upload was working fine until i get this error :
`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted`

Here is my function :

```
public function uploadFile() {
    // We upload only pdf for now
    if (isset($_FILES['fichier']['name']) && $_FILES['fichier']['type']=="application/pdf"){
      $tmp_name = $_FILES['fichier']['tmp_name'];
      // Avoid problem with space
      $nom = str_replace(' ','_',$_FILES['fichier']['name']);
      $taille = $_FILES['fichier']['size'];
      $type = $_FILES['fichier']['type'];
      $fp = fopen($tmp_name, 'rb');
      $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmp_name));
      $statement = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO document(nomfichier,fichier,typefichier,taillefichier) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
      $statement->bindParam(1, $nom);
      $statement->bindParam(2, $content, PDO::PARAM_LOB, $taille);
      $statement->bindParam(3, $type);
      $statement->bindParam(4, $taille);
      $statement->execute();
      $statement->closeCursor();
      // Redirect
      header('Location: documentation');
      die('redirect');
```

Edit : Problem comes from the database who choose a blob instead of longblob when regenerated

Comment: You might want to increase the memory limit and also check for the max. allowed file size for your uploads - http://stackoverflow.com/q/2184513/80836

Comment: I don't have access to the php.ini for the prod env, what should i do ?

Comment: I did the following: upload_max_filesize 300M, post_max_size 300M. I still have the error

Answer (score 0):

Check upload_max_filesize variable in your php.ini file.

It might be set to 128M , try increasing it to the desired value.

Comment: What if i don't have access to the file in the prod env ?

Comment: If your server allows PHP config changes through .htaccess, then you can create .htaccess file in the same folder as your php file and in that file write:

php_value upload_max_filesize 256M
php_value post_max_size 256M

Answer (score 0):

Check `post_max_size` & `upload_max_filesize`. `post_max_size` must be greater than `upload_max_filesize`. Set `upload_max_filesize` as per your requirement.

Comment: Can i ask you where i can find that ? Thank you

Comment: you need to check your php.ini file.You can view it 'phpinfo()' in your index.php also.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem exists in the line below:

```
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmp_name));
```

Here you are trying to read the content of the file, at this point you will get out of memory when the filesize is large.

So, increasing memory limit is not a better solution in this case. It's better to stream the file content rather than keeping hole content in memory.

Remove the above mentioned line, also replace the following line:

```
$statement->bindParam(2, $content, PDO::PARAM_LOB, $taille);
```

with

```
$stmt->bindColumn(2, $fp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
```

`PDO::PARAM_LOB` tells PDO to map the data as a stream